# Is it possible to compare 2 images on React Native?

Tags: reactjs, image, compare, native, pixelmatch

I'm trying to compare 2 images on React Native to get differences of them.

Example;

The second image is different 7% from the 1st photo.

Or

There are 200 different pixels.

I've installed pixelmatch and converted images to base64 and buffer. Unfortunately I couldn't get any response as i expect. Finally I would like to ask you if it is possible.